# locate file from outside a sub-directory in CI

Tags: codeigniter

I have two codeigniter installs in my CI project. But in my second codeigniter install I am having trouble calling a path from outside of the install folder.

**Project Layout:**

```
application folder
download folder
image folder
install folder "This contains own index.php and application folder"
system folder
index.php "main index.php"
```

The area I am having trouble call path from outside is the install folder. I need to be able to locate the first application folder.

Example what having problem.

**This Code Here Finds In Install Application Folder. Which is where this view file is located**

```
<tr>
<td><?php echo FCPATH . 'application/config/database.php'; ?></td>
<td class="align_right"><?php echo is_writable(FCPATH . 'application/config/database.php') ? '<span class="text-success">Writable</span>' : '<span class="text-danger">Unwritable</span>'; ?></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And displays **C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\install\application/config/database.php**

But need it to be able to pick up the main directory applications folder. So would look like this **C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\application/config/database.php**

**I do not want to touch anything in the install index.php**

APPPATH Does not work because the install folder has its own application folder Need to get the apppath from outside install folder.

Comment: how about $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/application/config/database.php'

Comment: can not pick up project name C:/xampp/htdocs/application/config/database.php on php view file: <?php echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/application/config/config.php'; ?>

Comment: Got it working this way now  <tr>
<td><?php echo dirname(FCPATH) . '/application/config/config.php'; ?></td>
<td class="align_right"><?php echo is_writable(dirname(FCPATH) . '/application/config/config.php') ? '<span class="text-success">Writable</span>' : '<span class="text-danger">Unwritable</span>'; ?></td>
</tr>

Answer (score 0):

Got it working this way now

```
<tr> <td><?php echo dirname(FCPATH) . '/application/config/config.php'; ?></td> <td class="align_right"><?php echo is_writable(dirname(FCPATH) . '/application/config/config.php') ? '<span class="text-success">Writable</span>' : '<span class="text-danger">Unwritable</span>'; ?></td> </tr>`
```